# javassist working in debug mode not in run

Tags: java, javassist

I'm working on javassist. I need to edit one method. Everything is working fine in debug mode, but when I ran it, it is failing to take the updated bytecode. I have no idea. Here is my code

```
CtClass classA = classPool.get("com.ClassA");
CtMethod sayHiMethod = classA.getDeclaredMethod("sayHi");
System.out.println("Going to pront");
sayHiMethod.insertBefore("{ System.out.println(\"popload\");}");
classA.writeFile();

Class c = classLoader.loadClass("com.ClassA");
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("sayHi");
Object obj = m.invoke(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when running in debug mode, your class is loaded before Javassist has a chance to instrument your class. If the class is already loaded, you will observe the original code.

An alternative approach to redefining your class that is not vulnerable to this would be [using a Java agent](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Easily-Create-Java-Agents-with-ByteBuddy) for instrumenting your code.

Comment: Ya it is good idea, but I can't include any agent. It is not acceptable.